# JS is included, but won't fire on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a js script that is supposed to fix my side menu on scroll. It shows it being included in the `view source` and if I copy/paste my code into console to auto-fire it, it works perfectly.

How can I figure out why it won't fire on load? No errors are thrown either. The file in question has 2 functions, the first is to fix the menu to to top and the second deals with changing content out by checking checkboxes.

Here is my script:

```
    // FIX SIDE BAR AFTER SCROLL
        $(window).load(function() {
console.log('test');
$("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var o = $(this.hash);
            if (o = o.length ? o : $("[name=" + this.hash.slice(1) + "]"), o.length) return $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: o.offset().top
            }, 900), !1
        }
    });
console.log('test2');
$(window).load(function() {
    var o = $(".sticky").offset().top,
        t = function() {
            var t = $(window).scrollTop();
            t > o ? $(".sticky").addClass("stuck") : $(".sticky").removeClass("stuck")
        };
    t(), $(window).scroll(function() {
        t()
    });
console.log('test3');
});

//RADIO BUTTON CONTENT CHANGER
      $(function(){ 
    $('input[name="pricing-radios"]').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).val()=='pricing1') {

            //change to "show update"
             $(".pricing-engage-chng").text("179");
             $(".pricing-engage-chng-additional").text(".01");
             $(".pricing-crm-chng").text("214");
             $(".pricing-crm-chng-additional").text(".01");
             $(".upgrade-price").text(".0025");


        } else if ($(this).val()=='pricing2') { 
             $(".pricing-engage-chng").text("699");
             $(".pricing-engage-chng-additional").text(".005");
             $(".pricing-crm-chng").text("714");
             $(".pricing-crm-chng-additional").text(".006");
             $(".upgrade-price").text(".0015");

        } else if ($(this).val()=='pricing3') {
             $(".pricing-engage-chng").text("3,499");
             $(".pricing-engage-chng-additional").text(".0025");
             $(".pricing-crm-chng").text("3,514");
             $(".pricing-crm-chng-additional").text(".00325");
             $(".upgrade-price").text(".00075");
        } 

    });

    });

    });
```

My code seems to work in my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLbuu4sr/)** and as I said, copy and pasting my code into my console will fire my command and yield the desired result.

You can see the live page **[here](https://www-salsalabs-com.sandbox.hs-sites.com/online-advocacy-software/pricing)** as well.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are u including jquery multiple times?

Comment: Yes, that is all included because if you look on the page, you can click those 3 radio/check buttons and it will change the content out.

Comment: Where do you see it included several times? I see it twice, one for 1.11 and one for 2.1. Edit: removed one of the jQuerey mentions

Comment: You should NOT include multiple versions of jQuery

Comment: @epascarello the framework we are on includes it and it was included again by someone before me I suppose. It is removed now, just 1.11 and jquery-migrate now

Comment: Well the fiddle is fired onload and your script in your page is fired on document ready. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: @epascarello swapped `$( document ).ready(function() {` to `$( document ).load(function() {` Still nothing..

Comment: should be window and not document. Did you add console lines to see if it is called? Did you add console lines to see if it finds any elements you are trying to select?

Comment: I will swap to window, as far as console lines, should I just run `console.log('test');` before the function is called, then after? and see if it returns 2 tests. Edit it calls the first two tests, but not the 3rd (Will update above code so you can see.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I figured this out:

The framework we use has an auto-minify function in it. So when I pulled the old code through, this part is *technically* minified. So my `vars` were returning unknown elements.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var o = $(".sticky").offset().top,
        t = function() {
            var t = $(window).scrollTop();
            t > o ? $(".sticky").addClass("stuck") : $(".sticky").removeClass("stuck")
        };
    t(), $(window).scroll(function() {
        t()
    });
```

I ended up rewriting a function to add the class and simplified it a little more and came up with this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    //if less than or = to 350 add class
    if (scroll >= 350) {
        $(".sticky").addClass("stuck");
    // else remove class
    } else {
        $(".sticky").removeClass("stuck");
    }
    });
```

Now this one gets minified, but everything is predefined and is readable.

Comment: Yes I was going to post this same thing - one reason NOT to write code as you had i.e. over optimization, missing semi-colons, function name IN the function as a new variable etc. AND depending upon how you load the script the window.onload might have already fired.